# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: unknown error: unsupported protocol

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I added all the links from web-page in `Arraylist` and then hit all the URLs one by one.

```
public class Redirectionlinked1 
{
    public static List findAllLinks(WebDriver driver)
    { 
        List <WebElement> elementList = new ArrayList();
        elementList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        elementList.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img")));

        List finalList = new ArrayList();
        for(WebElement element : elementList)
        {
            if (element.getAttribute("href") != null)
            {
                finalList.add(element);
            }
        }
        return finalList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Softwares\\gecko\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(" http://testsite.com");
        List <WebElement > allImages = findAllLinks(driver);

        System.out.println("Total number of elements found " + allImages.size());
        driver = new ChromeDriver ();
        URI uri =null;
        for (WebElement element : allImages) {
        if (!driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(element.getAttribute("href")) && driver.)
        {
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.get(element.getAttribute("href"));
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println(element.getAttribute("href"));
            uri = new URI(driver.getCurrentUrl());
            try 
            {
                if(uri.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase("SpecificDomain.net"))
                {
                    System.out.println(" Redirected URL-->> "+element.getAttribute("href"));
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Code works as expected (it launches the URL in browser) for first link later throws an error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: unknown error:
>   unsupported protocol
>         (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 131 milliseconds
>       Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '3169782', time: '2016-09-29 10:24:50 -0700'
>       System info: host: 'ETPUN-LT009', ip: '192.168.2.193', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_111'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.26.436362
>   (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),
>   userDataDir=C:\scoped_dir12784_32532}, takesHeapSnapshot=true,
>   pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
>       Session ID: df813868289a8f15f947ac620b3b1882
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:164)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:636)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
>         at Practices.Redirectionlinked1.main(Redirectionlinked1.java:99)

My configurations are :-

> Chrome - Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
>
> Geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64
>
> Windows -7
>
> Java - 1.8.1

Comment: Just a guess - you got a leading space in your url for the get() method.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I also tried with trim but no success. driver.get(element.getAttribute("href").trim());

Comment: I was talking of the driver.get() method -- driver.get(" http://testsite.com"); -- you have a space at the beginning. The error you are getting seems to mention this line. Try removing the space and check if it works

Comment: YES, to remove this (" testsite.com")  leading space, tried with trim function but no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be because there are links in you website with hre that looks like `#`, `resources/123.img` which are not complete URLS and triggering a get would result in the exception. You should put a check to ensure the urls are valid. This can be donw by using a comparison using `link.startsWith("http://") || link.startsWith("https://")`

There are other places also in which you test would fail.

1. `finalList` is declared as a List and returned. This ,must be changed to List and should be populated with the link valued. This is because we you have a for loop in which you are calling driver.get(newLink) which would reset all the WebElement objects in the `finalList` since they are found earlier and give an exception.
2. `img` tags do not have `href`. Instead use 'src'.

Here is the code after all those changes. Please be aware that there could be other conditions to check whether the URL is valid or not which I have not listed here.

```
    public static List<String> findAllLinks(WebDriver driver) {

        // Declare finalList as string.
        List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Get the a tags
        List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        // get the img tags
        elementList.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("img")));

        for (WebElement element : elementList) {
            // a tags have "href", img tags have src
            String link = element.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("a") ? element.getAttribute("href")
                    : element.getAttribute("src");
            // Check if link is not null and whether is a valid link by checking
            // starts with http or https
            if (link != null && (link.startsWith("http://") || link.startsWith("https://"))) {
                finalList.add(link);
            }
        }
        return finalList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                "E:\\Softwares\\gecko\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://testsite.com");
        List<String> allLinks = findAllLinks(driver);

        System.out.println("Total number of elements found " + allLinks.size());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        URI uri = null;
        for (String link : allLinks) {
            if (!driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(link)) {
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                driver.get(link);

                Thread.sleep(500);

                System.out.println(link);
                uri = new URI(driver.getCurrentUrl());
                try {
                    if (uri.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase("SpecificDomain.net")) {
                        System.out.println("Redirected URL-->> " + link);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently got the error org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:282)

In my case, it was because I was using Cucumber 5.5.0 & when I tried to pass a full url as a variable in the Scenario Outline data table, Cucumber got confused & caused Selenium to have an error.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your selenium web driver .It is compatiblity issues with webdriver and your browser version.
I updated my pom file with latest version of chrome web driver and it worked. Upgrading the chrome web driver Version  to 3.9.1 and above also resolves the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-5</version>
</dependency>
```